# DICTIONARY KEYERROR :how to use backslash as a key in python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, backslash

```
syntaxes={
        '>':"greater than",
        "<": "less than",
        "*": "multiplication",
        "+": "addition",
        '/': "forward slash"
        '\': "back slash" # String literal is unterminatedPylance

    }
    
input='>'
print(syntaxes[input])
```

I am trying to use the back slash as a key "" in python ,but it is not letting me and throwing error

Comment: You need to escape you backslash `'\\'`. And you're missing a `,` in your `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to use "\\" double backslash everywhere where ever you need only a single backslash.
In dictionary key as well as while providing input.

syntaxes={
        '>':"greater than",
        "<": "less than",
        "*": "multiplication",
        "+": "addition",
        '/': "forward slash",
        '\\': "back slash" # String literal is unterminatedPylance

    }
input='\\'
print(syntaxes[input])
```